# Doctrine2 - check if associated entry was deleted (unidirectional relationship)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Application is build on Symfony2 and Doctrine2.

I'm having unidirectional relationship OneToMany and when the associated entity entry has been deleted the reference column is still set to point to the deleted entry and this is the right behavior because it's just unidirectional association. But this is causing me a problem in a twig template because if I'm going to try to load that it will throw an error entity was not found. I was trying to check in twig using is defined but there was no difference. What would be the best way to check that if the associated entry hasn't been deleted?

Entity example:

```
class Programme
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Form")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="form_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
     private $form;
    ...
}
```

Twig check:

```
{% if programme.form is defined %}
    //always getting here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the InnoDB engine for Mysql you can add

```
onDelete="SET NULL"
```

To your relationship so when the referenced entity is deleted the field will be set to null.

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="form_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
```

This way you dont have links to missing entities at all and it is no longer a twig issue.

**If using soft delete:**

Then im assuming that you are flagging that entity somehow as deleted and you can do something like:

```
{% if programme.form.deleted|default(true) != true %}
    //Your form will always be defined but if 
    //its deleted then you want to ignore it
{% endif %}
```

This assumes that you have a `deleted` column on form. It also uses the default of true for entries that do not have forms.

If you want to simplify this check you can implement a method like `isNotDeleted()` on your form entity:

```
public function isNotDelete()
{
    return $this->deleted === false;
}
```

then your twig check would just be:

```
{% if programme.form.notDeleted|default(false) %}
    //do stuff
{% endif %}
```

You still need the default filter because if an entity does not have the form association then a method not found exception will be thrown.

Comment: Hi,
This is looking very good but it might not suit me because I'm not completely deleting those entries but using just soft delete Sorry that I didn't mention that earlier.

Comment: Then you can just check what ever column you are using to indicate the "soft delete". Using the default twig filter will stop you from getting method not found exceptions for entities that dont have a form.

Answer (score 0):

Check like :

```
{% if programme.form %}
    //always getting here
{% endif %}
```

no need for 'is defined'.

Comment: I've tried that as well. I think the problem with that is that actually the referenced id is still available for that record even if the associated record is deleted, but how to check it?

Comment: If you want to check reference id is there, then If it will go inside if condition the reference id is there. try to print {{ programme.form.feldName }}. If you want to set null on delete of parent row delete, just use OnDelete="SET NULL" in your entity relation. If you no longer need that child row on delete of parent row then put onDelete="CASCADE". Then you have no longer need to check in template file like this. :)